# Не отображается яндекс карта

Tags: laravel, vue.js, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

У меня проект ларавел + vue.js

В app.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
const app = createApp({});

import Maps from './components/Maps.vue';
app.component('maps', Maps);

import VueYandexMaps from 'vue-yandex-maps';
app.use(VueYandexMaps, {
  apiKey: 'ВАШ_API_КЛЮЧ',
});
```

В компоненте maps

```
<template>
  <yandex-map :center="[55.751574, 37.573856]" :zoom="10"></yandex-map>
</template>

<script>

</script>
      
<style scoped>

</style>
```

После этого в шаблоне его рендерю на странице

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Карта</h1>
        <maps></maps>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Блок с картой не отображается вообще, но в html коде есть такой тег

```
<yandex-map center="55.751574,37.573856" zoom="10"></yandex-map>
```

В package.json зависимость установлена

```
 "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.1",
        "npm-watch": "^0.11.0",
        "vue-yandex-maps": "^0.11.18"
    }
```

Кто-нибудь сможет подсказать как решить эту проблему?